# Asp.net project is not recognising one of the folders in my class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, class-library

I am developing a project using Visual Studio 2008 in C#, I have added the class library within the project and set up the relevant references and used the relevant using statements.
It seems to be a problem with just this one folder. can anyone help?

this is the error message:

> Error 28  The type or namespace name
>   'Domain' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Forestry.SchoolLibrary'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Projects\SchoolofForestry\trunk\Source\School\Account\Presenter\EditAccountPresenter.cs  26  40  School

these are my using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Forestry.SchoolLibrary.Core.Domain;
using Forestry.SchoolLibrary.Properties;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a type named `Domain` and a namespace that ends with `Domain`. This is bad as it generates some problems (for example the one you are encountering). So I would recommend you removing the `Domain` part of the namespace or you could use the [`global::`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx) identifier for a type:

```
var domain = new global::Forestry.SchoolLibrary.Core.Domain.Domain();
```

Of course as you can see this might get ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are recieving doesn't seem to match your using statements. In the error, .NET is searching for the following namespace:

```
Forestry.SchoolLibrary.Domain
```

And in your using statement, you're referencing:

```
Forestry.SchoolLibrary.Core.Domain
```

I would check if you are explicitly referencing Forestry.SchoolLibrary in the line of code causing the error.